# Stored procedure To view table based on Given parameters

Tags: sql-server

i have this procedure and i want to modify it to select rows where the given parameters are not null

```
Create PROC ViewclassCourses
(
@pClassID int = null,
@pcourseID int = null,
@pMinMark decimal(5,2)=null,
@pMaxMark decimal(5,2)=null
)
as

select ClassID,CourseID,minmark,maxmark from ClassCourses
Go
```

for example if i type
ViewclassCourses @pclassID=1,@pMaxMark=100
it works like

```
select ClassID,CourseID,minmark,maxmark from ClassCourses where @pclassID=1 and    @pMaxMark=100'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it that you want to use the parameters only if they are non null?
At my work we usually do like this:

```
 Create PROC ViewclassCourses
    (
    @pClassID int = null,
    @pcourseID int = null,
    @pMinMark decimal(5,2)=null,
    @pMaxMark decimal(5,2)=null
    )
    as

    select ClassID,CourseID,minmark,maxmark from ClassCourses
    where ClassId = coalesce(@pClassID, ClassId)
    and CourseID = coalesce(@pcourseID , CourseID)
    and minmark = coalesce(@pMinMark , minmark)
    and maxmark = coalesce(@pMaxMark , maxmark)
    Go
```

You could also write `where @pClassId is null or ClassId = @pClassId`. We've just adopted the "`COALESCE` pattern".

Answer (score 0):

@pMaxMark    Create PROC ViewclassCourses
    (
    @pClassID int = null,
    @pcourseID int = null,
    @pMinMark decimal(5,2)=null,
    @pMaxMark decimal(5,2)=null
    )
    as

```
 SELECT ClassID,CourseID,minmark,maxmark FROM ClassCourses WHERE @pClassID IS NOT NULL AND @pcourseID IS NOT NULL 
Go
```